# redux test Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: react-redux, jestjs

I am not using `redux-thunk`. this keeps error-ing and I am not sure how to fix it. The examples I see online use `redux-thunk` which I am not using

my repo is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/plentific-uo68b?eslint=1&fontsize=14) and the file I am trying to test is in `tests\actions\...`

[image: error of action]

My action that is being called in the test

```
import axios from "axios";
var CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
let fetch_cancel;

export const FETCH_CATEGORIES = "fetch_categories";

export async function fetchCategories() {
  fetch_cancel && fetch_cancel();
  const request = await axios.get(
    `https://d1i9eedhsgvpdh.cloudfront.net/production-plentific-static/api-cache/find-a-pro/api/v1/categories/all.json`,
    {
      cancelToken: new CancelToken(function executor(c) {
        // An executor function receives a cancel function as a parameter
        fetch_cancel = c;
      })
    }
  );
  return {
    type: FETCH_CATEGORIES,
    payload: request
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that your actions must be plain objects. For example:

```
store.dispatch({
  type: 'ADD_TODO',
  text: 'Understand the middleware'
})
```

If you make an async request, you can't just return an object, because you need to wait for the request to finish. If you return too early, you return a Promise.

However, I cannot reproduce your error in your sandbox.

Comment: I have added a screenshot. all my actions have `async` on the function name and `await` before axios call.

Comment: I understand what you mean as its returning a Promise but how can i fix this without using `redux-thunk`?